# How to automate DCom settings/configuration using Powershell

Tags: powershell, dcom

How to automate the DCom settings for the below manual settings:
https://documentation.softwareag.com/natural/nat6313win/ops/ops-nxdcom.html

I haven't been able to find a concrete method of doing what I'm aiming to achieve so any help would be great

I've tried using this snippet of code but getting an error for some reason:

```
# Create a new COM object for Component Services
$comAdmin = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
# Get the "My Computer" node
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$applications.Populate()
$computers = $applications.GetCollection("Computers")
$computers.Populate()
$computer = $computers | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "My Computer" }

# Set the default authentication level to "Connect"
$computer.Value("DefaultAuthenticationLevel") = 2 # 2 corresponds to "Connect"
$computer.SaveChanges()
```